# Probability of a Gamma distribution using binomial probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, gamma-distribution

Suppose we have a distribution $Y\sim Gamma(\alpha=4, \beta=7)$

Given $F(Y)=\sum_{i=\alpha}^{n}{n \choose i}y^i(1-y)^{n-i}$, where $n=\alpha+\beta+1$, I need to find $P(Y \leq .7)=F(.7)$ using binomial tables.

By substituting the parameters, this gives $F(.7)=\sum_{i=4}^{10}{10 \choose i}.7^i(.3)^{10-i}=.989$

Can someone please explain to me how to get $.989$ from the sum using this table? 
I know it corresponds to $a=6$ and $p=.4$ in the $n=10$ part, but I do not understand why we must look at this cell with $p=.3$ instead of $p=.7$

Thanks!
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We make a few observations
$$P(Y\geq 4)= \sum_{i = 4}^{10} p^i (1-p)^{10-i} = 1-P(Y\leq 3) = 1-\sum_{i=0}^3p^i(1-p)^{10-i}$$

The bounds on your table are $0$ to $a$. Hence, we look up $n=10, a = 3, p = .7$ and get
$$\sum_{i=0}^3p^i(1-p)^{10-i}\approx .011.$$
So our approximation is
$$1-P(Y\leq 3) = 1-\sum_{i=0}^3p^i(1-p)^{10-i}\approx 1-.011 =.989$$

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me understand.

Comment: Sure no problem. Just to be clear, I helped answer the binomial summation question. I don't know about your notation, but I think you are calculating $P(Y\leq .7)$ incorrectly.